# Equal genomic intervals between samples

Tags: r, overlap, genome

I would like to found the exactly same genomic intervals shared between samples (`NE_id`).

My Input:

```
chr  start_call   end_call  NE_id 
chr1    150         200      NE01
chr1    150         200      NE02
chr2    100         150      NE01
chr2    100         160      NE02
chr3    200         300      NE01   
chr3    200         300      NE02
```

My expected output:

```
chr  start_call   end_call  NE_id 
chr1    150         200      NE01, NE02   
chr3    200         300      NE01, NE02
```

In this example the `chr2` genomic interval have some overlap, however it don´t correspond to the exact same genomic interval (size difference == `10`).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your output right? same ID twice?

Comment: Look into the package `GenomicRanges`. You can do a lot of this stuff in base R yes, but you are reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `dat` is the data, you could try:

```
res <-aggregate(NE_id~., data=dat, FUN=I)
res[sapply(res$NE_id,length)>1,]
#    chr  start_call end_call     NE_id
# 3 chr1        150      200 NE01, NE02
# 4 chr3        200      300 NE01, NE02
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. However, in my big data frame the last collumn `NE_id` give me numbers instead the originals IDs (NE01, NE02, NE03...). Have you some idea why?? Thank you

Comment: @user3091668. Check whether the column is factor.dat$NE_id <- factor(dat$NE_id)res <-aggregate(NE_id~., data=dat, FUN=I)
> res[sapply(res$NE_id,length)>1,]
   chr start_call end_call NE_id
3 chr1        150      200  1, 2
4 chr3        200      300  1, 2

Comment: `user3091668`.  You could convert it to character. dat$NE_id <- as.character(dat$NE_id) and check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a GenomicRanges solution

```
library(GenomicRanges)
NE01 <- GRanges(c("chr1","chr2","chr3"),
         IRanges(c(150,100,200),c(200,150,300)),
         ID=rep("NE01",3))
NE02 <- GRanges(c("chr1","chr2","chr3"),
            IRanges(c(150,100,200),c(200,160,300)),
            ID=rep("NE02",3))
findOverlaps(NE01,NE02,type="equal")
```

I only have to type it all out because I don't have your data frame, you can just specify data frame columns when making the GRanges object.